# how to fetch the old code from git repository

Tags: git, repository, fetch

I think this is the simplest  question  but i am very first to the git .
So can you please any body help me out.
That is how to fetch the old code from the git repository and how to get the old code from the
local(git repo in on my machine) repository

Comment: Have you tried `git clone` and `git checkout`? They are handy sometimes ;)

Comment: yes i know that , but i am getting the very recent code,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With git, you always have a copy of the complete repository including the history.

First, clone your repository:

```
git clone <repo_url>
```

Then checkout the old commit

```
git checkout <commit>
```

Comment: what will do the 'checkout '. Really i am the beginner so i don't know

Comment: checkout <commit> will change your working copy to that specific commit. I *really* recommend to look at some documentation, e.g. http://git-scm.com/doc or you will shoot yourself into the foot sooner rather than later.

Comment: +1 to the above comment for the Pro Git book- it's really fabulous.

Comment: Thank you  for providing the way